# plus minus button with specific parent input doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, increment

as you can see here [jsfiddle.net/TTU4Z/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/TTU4Z/1/)
The jquery code in question is below and if i run it without all my code (like in jsfiddle) it run perfectly. but with all my code doesn't run.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// This button will increment the value
$('.plus').click(function(e){
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[id='+fieldName+']').val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        // Increment
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
});
// This button will decrement the value till 1
$(".minus").click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[id='+fieldName+']').val());
    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        // Decrement one
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
});

});
```

Clicking on "add" button all is good, but when you click in one of minus or plus button it delete all.

It should increase or decrease the val of the relative input as you can see, but nothing change if i try to edit everything in those functions.
What to do?

Comment: That's a lot of duplicated code. You should use one function for both, passing in whether it should add or subtract through a `data-*` attribute or a `hasClass()` check. Also, `field` isn't a valid HTML attribute: you should use `data-field` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are appending elements dynamically you have to use [**`event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in this situation. Actually the registered events are not invoking in your context, that's why the `buttons` are exhibiting their original behavior.

Try,

```
$(document).on('click','.plus',function(e){
```

and

```
$(document).on('click','.minus',function(e){
```

Additionally, the `selector` that you are framing dynamically contains some `meta-characters`, just pass that as a `string` or you have to `escape` it, in order to make your code work properly.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/TTU4Z/7/)

---

New Demo after fixing your concatenation issues. And in that demo, i just removed the attribute selectors like `[id='blah']` and replaced that with `$('#blah')`.

### [DEMO - I](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/TTU4Z/8/)

Comment: Hey man, your code does not let you change more than one element due to the error I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Actually i thought that OP has intentionally did that, that's why i just given a solution to over come the meta-character issue.

Comment: I think that maybe cause it has never worked OP never saw the problem. Fix your fiddle and I will +1 ya :)

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I have updated the post, but you deserve the upvote for pointing that issue. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LfNmh/

You had your x variable inside the code string where it should have been in the code. line 15 ..

```
var numPortata = '<td><button class="minus" field="portata'+x+'">-</button><input id="portata'+x+'" type="number" name="numPortata[]" value="1" size="10" min="1" max="10" step="1" required><button class="plus" field="portata'+x+'">+</button></td>';
```

I also changed the code so that the events are attached at the document level as Rajaprabhu said.